# Convert osm data to png using Mapnik

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, mapnik

As stated in the title, is it possible for Mapnik to output png tiles from osm data let's say from http://download.geofabrik.de/ without the need of creating a stylesheet.xml?

Edit: Not just one png file but a while bunch of png files per tile and per zoom for each tile that make up the whole tile itself.

Comment: It's possible to generate pngs of course, but you need a stylesheet. Mapnik don't know the way you want the osm data be represented. Did you mean that you don't want to create and populate postgis database to store data, and use osm file directly?

Comment: I found out from this source http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example that you can serve tiles by combining series of png images to form a tile. But I also found out from switchosm website that you can store the tile data in the db and access them. Which one the better option? My client wants the first option but is open to the second solution, what can you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

(Regarding your comment) That's not how it works. [OpenLayers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers), [Leaflet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Leaflet) and similar libraries need a tile server for fetching these [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). They can't read directly from a database. The tile server instead needs a local database for creating (rendering) these tiles.

Thus your client will either have to run a tile server itself, or you will have to run a tile server for your client (see [serving tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) on switch2osm), or your client will have to access a public tile server (see [using tiles](https://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/) on switch2osm). The third solution requires to conform to the usage policy / terms of services of the [tile server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Alternative_OpenStreetMap_Tile_Providers) you have chosen. Note that there are also paid-for tile servers available.

Also note that there are alternative approaches for [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Renderers) smaller areas without the need of a full tile server installation, for example by using Maperitive or TileMill.